# Sprind Date Rest Custom JsonSerializable

Tags: json, spring-data-rest

I want to get the date in the format "yyyymmdd" in my Sprind data rest aplication. To do that I made a custom json serializable. This is the code:

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{

private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddmm");
static private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonDateSerializer.class);
@Override
public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen,SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    String fecha = dateFormat.format(value);

    log.debug("NNN Valor de la fecha: " + fecha);

    jgen.writeString(fecha);
}
}
```

And, in my entity, I used the annotation "@JsonSerialize" on the getter method:

```
@Column(name="cumpleanos")
private Date birthday;

@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
}
public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
}
```

But it doesn't work. I am still getting the date like a long number. What am I missing?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: - Which version of SD Rest are you using? - Which versions of Jackson are you using? There are two different Jackson modules that contain classes with similar names: org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize vs. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize Which one are you using? Cheers,
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom: I'm using the "org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize". My spring data rest version is 1.0.0.RELEASE. The Jackson's version is 1.9.10.